# How to solve this Linker error?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010, operating-system, program-entry-point

I have a created a program starts with OS_main instead if int main

```
OS_MAIN()
{
    // it is performing some function calls here
}
```

If i run my program : I am getting linker error as

> LNK2019: unresolved external symbol_main referenced in function_tmainCRTStartup.

how to solve this error ??

I am using microsoft visual studio IDE.

Comment: `#define OS_MAIN() int main()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linker errors happen when the definition of a function or variable that is being used cannot be found.  If you have this preprocessor definition somewhere...

```
#define OS_MAIN main
```

...and you're doing this...

```
int OS_MAIN(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

... that is fine, however, if you're using `OS_MAIN` instead of `main` that won't work.  Every program needs a `main`.  That is where every program starts.

Comment: In case of operating system task : Do I need a main ??

Comment: @user3127246 What do you mean by "operating system task"? If you are writing an operating system, you need to start with a boot loader, not a C program with the C runtime library.